# Laravel - Query 3 tables based on relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I am wanting to query 3 seperate tables at once. The main one is `Criteria`, the two `has Many` tables, linked by `criteria_id` are `Bedrooms` and `Properties`.

A `Criteria` can have many `Bedrooms` and many `Properties`:

[image: Screenshot]

**Criteria Model**

```
public function bedrooms()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Bedroom');
}

public function properties()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Property');
}
```

I'm unsure if this is possible, but I want to query both of these tables, as well as `Criteria` to see which criteria has a certain bedroom and a certain property type. Please note, there could be multiple bedrooms and properties stored for each criteria_id.

So far, my query is:

```
$criterias = Criteria::select('id')
        ->where('min', '<=', Input::get('single_value'))
        ->lists('id');
```

My only logical explanation is -

> Get all Criteria where Min <= Value and Criteria.Bedrooms = 1 and
>   Criteria.Properties = 5.

As if to loop through and see if a criteria has a bedroom / property with that value stored.

Many thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for only criteria that meet your constraints, you can use `whereHas()` on the Bedroom and Property relationships.  Then add your `where()` and `lists()`.

```
$bedroom_id = '1';
$property_id = '5';

$criteria = Criteria::whereHas('bedrooms', function($q) use ($bedroom_id) {
    $q->where('bedroom', $bedroom_id);
})->whereHas('properties', function($q) use ($property_id) {
    $q->where('property', $property_id);
})->where('min', '<=', Input::get('single_value'))->lists('id');
```

`Criteria.Bedrooms = 1 and Criteria.Properties = 5` was a little vague, but I added it in where they should go.  I'm guessing you actually meant the `id` of `1` and `5` respectively so it would be getting all criteria that have both a bedroom of id 1 and a property of id 5.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Eager Loading](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#eager-loading) the relationships

```
$criterias = Criteria::with('bedrooms', 'properties')
            ->where('min', '<=', Input::get('single_value'))
            ->lists('id');
```

Comment: I want to query the bedroom and properties tables, though. Where a criteria has 1 bedroom and a property of 5, for example. I'd have to query this again?